# Pass value to an other compoment via routerLink in Ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, hyperlink, routerlink

I would like to pass value to another compoment ex: a name of country, and use it on the other compoment

I make the link like that and i want to send the value "France" to another compoment (via dataHere) :

```
  <ion-card-header>
    <ion-img class="logo-flag-greece" alt="mylogo" ></ion-img>
    <span routerLink="/tabs/result" dataHere="France" class="text">France</span>

  </ion-card-header>
```

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in you html file

```
<ion-card-header>
    <ion-img class="logo-flag-greece" alt="mylogo" ></ion-img>
    <span (click)="show_result()" dataHere="France" class="text">France</span>
  </ion-card-header>
```

and in your ts file

```
 import {Router} from "@angular/router";
  ...
  ...
  constructor(private router:Router){}

show_result(){
this.router.navigate(["/tabs/result"],{
  queryParams: {
    data: your_data
  }
}); 
}
```

and in your result.page.ts file

```
 import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
   ...
   ...
   constructor(private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute){}
ionViewDidEnter(){
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    this.country_data = params['data'];
  });

}
```

But I don't recommend this work around. Instead use "service". Your can pass data from one page to another this way. Learn more about service in https://edupala.com/ionic-service/

Comment: Thanks body it is working , i will use service later to have something more robust